# Proving the identity of two functions

Tags: special-functions

```
F1[b_, r_] := 
  1/(2 π)      
    Integrate[
      x*BesselK[0, Sqrt[(r - x*Cos[y])^2 + x^2*Sin[y]^2]], 
      {x, 0,  b}, {y, 0, 2 π}];

F2[b_, r_] := 1 - b*BesselK[1, b]*BesselI[0, r];
```

Using Mathematica, I can find that `F1` and `F2` give the same values when `r <= b`. But I cannot prove that `F1` and `F2` are identical. Any help?

Comment: Since one of the functions is defined as a numerical evaluator, there is no way to make such a proof in Mathematica. I think you must reframe the question so that no numerics is involved.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP is asking for functionality that is not supported given the constraints the OP is putting on the solution.

Comment: You could try differentiating `F2` to see if that gives the integrand of `F1`.